# Ubuntu 22.04 Won't Boot On HP Elitebook 8470p

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader, hp

I have a HP Elitebook 8470p that had Windows 10 on it. It ran fine. I decided to install Ubuntu 22.04 on it. Installation seemed to go fine just like dozens of other times I've installed it but the laptop would not boot. It said BootDevice not found.

The HP PC Diagnostics UEFI would not detect a drive when trying a disk check. Bios system information could see and report the drive fine. Ubuntu live CD could see drive fine.

I decided to try a new SSD in the laptop with same results. Tried installing Ubuntu 22.04 5 or 6 times in total.

I checked Bios several times to make sure it was in legacy mode and boot order was correct but it wouldn't boot.

I then installed Windows 10 from a fresh bootable USB and Windows 10 installed and booted fine on the first try.

Any ideas?  Much appreciated.

Comment: On one HP laptop, the only way I could get it to boot grub2.efi was to rename the original boot file and then change grubx64.efi to that name. Yes, this is a hack, but it's been working well for years. See https://github.com/AnarchyLinux/installer/issues/400

Comment: You should install any UEFI machine in UEFI mode. Ubuntu supports UEFI mode since 2012!! And if installing Ubuntu alone, i.e., not as dual-boot with Windows no hack as the above is even needed. So, I suspect the main issue here stems from your decision to enable "Legacy"